# Module Theory for Singular Homology

Tags: reference-request, homology-cohomology

What are the results about modules that I should know for computing singular homology of spaces?

Comment: I would say at the very least the "linear algebra" aspect of module theory, how to handle exact sequences, and results about derived functors ($\operatorname{Tor}$, $\operatorname{Ext}$...). But your question is somewhat vague.

Comment: Well, I agree it is a bit vague, but I thought there would be some standard results you use in most cases..

Comment: It's mostly homological algebra (I know, not very surprising). I can recommend to you Weibel's *An introduction to homological algebra*, at least the first three chapters. I don't think you really need to know deep results about modules to study singular homology (things that are generally classified as "Commutative algebra").

Comment: At the very bare minimum, the stuff covered in Hatcher should be sufficient - this is just basic results on abelian groups, vector spaces, exact sequences, quotients, etc.

Comment: Well, the worst is that some exercises use much more. Today, I needed a result about projective modules for computing the homology of a pair..